# How to filter objects in django by hyperlink related field

Tags: python, django

I have a model called car which contains a property `session` which is a HyperLinkRelatedField

I am trying to filter the objects by that hyperlinkrelated field

I tried something like this:

```
session_url = "http://localhost:8000/v1/sessions/"+uuid+"/"
print cars.objects.filter(session=session_url)
```

I got this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'http://localhost:8000/v1/sessions/4c597c05-5e66-11e6-a79c-9801a78ed96d/'
```

The problem is, session is definetly not an integer, so I can not understand why this happens

here is how my serializer looks

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    altitude = serializers.FloatField()
    course = serializers.FloatField()
    session = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=False,
        queryset=Session.objects.all(),
        view_name="session-detail",
        lookup_field="uuid"
    )
    timestamp = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)
```

Any reason why this is not working ? and if it is wrong then how do we filter an object by a HyperLink in django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You field `session` is a serializer field, not a model field. In the DRF these fields are usually computed based on the model data. 
The `HyperlinkedRelatedField` offers an easy way of putting URLs to ressourses into a response. On the other other hand it contais too much hard to parse data to use it for queries to the ORM. To filter by a relation you need an object of the type the relation goes to or a value with the same type as the primary key. In your case an integer.

To solve your problem, I advise to use a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` instead of or in addition to your `HyperlinkedRelatedField`.

Seeing your code, an other solution could be to filter by the UUID, but you did not provide your models, so I can give a proper code example.

Comment: I was able to pass the session object into the filter and it worked. Thanks :)